# Can I use Firebase to control my app behavior?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

A while back, I had a crash course on Advanced Android, where the instructor taught about Firebase. Although, I don't remember the details, he said we could control our apps' behavior from Firebase console (e.g. by calling a Cloud function?). For example, then I can get a trigger in my app and in response, I can decide whether to serve certain functions and features to the user or not (like remove an onClickListener from a button) based on e.g. they have paid the project price or subscription fee.
Is it possible to do using Firebase?

Comment: The description of what you're trying to accomplish is kind of vague.  Perhaps you should start reading about Cloud Functions for Firebase to get a sense of [what it can do](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) (which is a lot of things).

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson I love you man, I have seen some of your videos! Thanks I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and experiment I was able to implement this functionality into my app.
First you need to add Firebase Messaging to your project. Then, create a subclass of FirebaseMessagingService. Inside the class, implement `onMessageReceived`, where you can access messages received from server:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNewToken: " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: activation: "+ remoteMessage.getData().get(Constants.ACTIVATION_KEY));
        boolean activation = Boolean.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get(Constants.ACTIVATION_KEY));

        //Save in preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplication().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCE_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Constants.ACTIVATION_KEY, activation);
        editor.apply();          
    }
}
```

Make sure you add this service in your Manifest file:

```
<service android:name="me.mehdi.utils.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

In your Firebase Console select Cloud Messaging from the left and hit "New message". While composing a new message, you'll notice a section "Advanced options" in addition to message text and message label. Under Advanced options, you can enter key-value pairs and send to the device you select from the dropdown menu and finally hit Send message. In your `onMessageReceived` method, you can read the key-value pair and update your app's shared preferences to activate or deactivate certain features.
[image]